# Is SuperUser Not the Right Place for Visio Questions?

Tags: support, down-votes, unanswered-questions, votes

I noticed in checking SuperUser that lots of Visio questions were popular and had multiple answers between 2009 and 2011. However, a quick scan shows that Visio questions asked after 2014 have rarely been answered, let alone voted on.

I have a Visio question that I posted which has not been answered and I just earned a "tumbleweed" badge, which seems like a dubious honor if I'm understanding the significance. Anyway, that is what prompted me to start investigating the prevalence and answership of Visio questions historically in SU.

Here's the question in question:
[How can I remove a Theme from One Shape of Many in Visio 2016](https://superuser.com/questions/1109937/how-can-i-remove-a-theme-from-one-shape-of-many-in-visio-2016)

I'm just trying to understand if I have my question in the right place, and if so, why hasn't anyone voted it up?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Its the right place. Or more precisely, there's no other "better" place for it. Visio is a bit 'niche' and there's not that many people who specifically trawl for visio questions I guess

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thanks for your answer, it was helpful. How do most users who are looking for questions to answer go about this "trawling" that you speak of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visio questions are on topic here. Microsoft Visio is desktop software and not a programming tool, so it fits here (as opposed to Stack Overflow or Web Apps).

Excerpted from the [help center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), emphasis mine:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - **computer software**, or
> - personal and home computer networking
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

As noted in the comments here, there might not be very many Visio experts on the site, so it could take a while for questions about it to get answered. You can make your questions even better - and therefore a little more likely to get answered - by including screenshots and specific steps (starting from as simple a base as possible) to reproduce problems, as appropriate

Comment: Thanks for confirming that @Ben N. Also, thanks for the tips about adding photos. Is there a best practice for how to add photos to SuperUser?

Comment: @EricHepperle-CodeSlayer2010 In the post editor window, there's an image button that you can use to upload an image, or even paste one from your clipboard! That's my preferred way to host images for SU.

Comment: Cool, I'll give that a try. I didn't know that Superuser was hosting images.